# continuous or going to

Tags: word-choice, tense, future-time

Please would you mind shipping directly to me as I **am shipping** to you next monday

Is it better to use going to, I don't think so because Iam going to do it for sure and I can't use present because it is something I do very rarely.

Comment: Try to clarify the question further. The sentence is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I actually only learned what this is called recently. It's not a term that's used often, but it's handy for explaining this bit of English grammar. "I **am shipping** to you next Monday" is an example of a ***futurate***. That is an expression of something that will happen in the future using the present tense.

It's simply using a present simple or progressive main verb with an extra phrase/clause to indicate when. It looks just like a fully future expression, but that "next Monday" is all it takes to make it semantically future time. The following are all practically equivalent:

> I **will ship** to you next Monday
>   I **will be shipping** to you next Monday
>   I **ship** to you next Monday
>   I **am shipping** to you next Monday

For some verbs, there would be a difference between the simple and the progressive, but in this case there isn't, in any practical sense. It's just another one of those little quirks of English.

Answer (score -1):

> I can't use present because it is something I do very rarely

I'm assuming that, by "present", you mean the *present tense*. If so, this is not a reason to choose a verb tense. The tense of a verb is only about *when* the action takes place; it doesn't have anything to do with how often the action happens.

If you intend to ship something in the future, "will ship" and "going to ship" are both correct:

> I will ship the package to you next Monday.
>
> I am going to ship the package to you next Monday.

("Will ship" is just the future tense of "to ship".)

There are some *very* subtle differences between "will" and "going to". In general, "will" is more confident than "going to" - so if you want to convey that you are certain about shipping the package, "will" is a bit better. But the difference between "will" and "going to" is very small; in almost all cases, they mean the same thing.